# Regex for checking address house number

Tags: regex

I'm using the following expression to validate a house number:

```
^\d{1,4}([a-zA-Z]{1,2}\d{1,3}|[a-zA-Z]{1,2}|)$
```

Now the requirement has changed to the following constraints:

- one number (25)
- one number w/ one letter (25A)
- one number w/ a second one divided by a hyphen (25-32)
- one number w/ a second one divided by a hyphen and one letter w/ blank (25-32 A)

How do I validate these w/ changes to the regex above?

Comment: You put a regex that doesn't show your efforts on solving your *current* problem. Tell us what you did and how it failed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only want to match those values, you might use a pattern to match 1 or more digits followed by an optional part that matches either `A-Z` OR a hyphen and 1+ digits optionally followed by a space and a char `A-Z`

```
^\d+(?:[A-Z]|-\d+(?: [A-Z])?)?$
```

- `^` Start of string
- `\d+` Match 1+ digits
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `[A-Z]` Match a char A-Z
  - `|` Or
  - `-\d+` Match
  - `(?: [A-Z])?`
- `)?` Close group and make it optional
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/PFlFU0/1)

Comment: Thanks, but w/ this it also matches '-25' && '25-'

Comment: @jmcclane If you only want to match those numbers, you could use anchors  `^\d+(?:[A-Z]|-\d+(?: [A-Z])?)?$` https://regex101.com/r/878RTX/1